# Cofoundry: How do I add a PageBlock inside a PageBlock?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, cofoundry

I want to be able to build a site from the design view. Utilising Bootstrap, I want to be able to add rows, add columns to my rows and then add text and images etc. to inside those columns.

I though I could do this by making both "row" and "column" page blocks but if I do this I can't add anything inside the row or column page blocks once they're on the page (as they're not page templates).

The image below shows me adding a Row PageBlock to the introduction section in the Cofoundry CMS BasicTestSite starter theme provided by Cofoundry. But I can only add things below it, not inside it.

[image]

I know one option would be to add rows to the PageTemplate, but the limits the CMS to only being able to work with the number of rows on the page template. I want to be able to **add rows and columns dynamically** without touching code.

PS: I'm new to Cofundry, so apologies if I'm using this terminology incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use [Nested Data Models](https://www.cofoundry.org/blog/14/introducing-nested-data-models) to achevie this, whereby your row data model can have a nested collection of columns. However nested data models aren't associated with a template, and it is up to the container block type to know how to render your model.